# ValvePython implementation causes Shell restart without error

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests, steam

Earlier this year, I wrote a script (Python 3.7) that does the following:

- Downloads/stores all the words from the English language from [here](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/csrg/share/dict/words?view=co&content-type=text/plain) using urllib

And then loops:

1) Chooses a word at random (random.choice)

2) Uses it as the search query for google images

3) Using BeautifulSoup, chooses a random image result between 1 and 5 and downloads it

4) Uploads it as my steam profile picture (with provided `sessionid`, `steamLogin`, and `steamLoginSecure` copied/pasted from my browser).

This script worked great. Lately, I wanted to automate obtaining the cookies required for step 4, so I implemented a step 1.5 that uses the [SteamValve package](https://steam.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to interact with Steam services.

This is where the problem comes in. The code I added is fairly simple:

```
def GetCookies():
    client = SteamClient()
    client.cli_login()
    webCookies = client.get_web_session_cookies()
    if webCookies == None:
        raise Exception("Unable to get web session. Try again later.")
    return {"steamLogin": webCookies.get("steamLogin"),
            "steamLoginSecure": webCookies.get("steamLoginSecure"),
            "sessionid": str(client.session_id),
            "steamid": str(client.steam_id)}
```

My script works great, except it now fails silently. The script will stop running, and print "RESTART: Shell." With cmd, it just closes. No errors are thrown. Using prints, I've been able to determine that it always happens at one of the three `urlopen` statements specifically I have in my script (step 0, step 2, or step 3). It never fails on step 4 (uploading). When it fails, I can't catch any errors. Also, it doesn't always fail in the same spot. If I call `GetCookies()` before step 0, it often fails on that step. If I move the call to afterwards, it'll usually pass all the steps and then fail on step 2 the second time around, and then go on to fail on step 2 the first time. But sometimes it passes step 2 and then fails on step 3. GetCookies() always runs successfully.

Basically, it's inconsistent where it fails and it doesn't throw any errors. The only thing that's consistent is that it fails on `urlopen` statements and only fails after `GetCookies()` is called. I tried running the code in an online debugger and the code never crashed. What could the reasons be for my script failing silently after implementing `GetCookies()`, and on `urlopen` statements specifically? I've tried moving `GetCookies()` to another file. Should I run another thread or something? Could some lingering process from `GetCookies()` be causing overhead and causing the program to crash?

The script is kinda long, but I can edit it in if you want. I'd appreciate any advice on how I can go about preventing these silent restarts.

Comment: Where is that `"RESTART: Shell."` happening? In IDLE?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, forgot to specify that.